# сумма чисел в векторе

Tags: c++, вектор

мне нужно разделить вектор на произвольное количество частей, затем посчитать сумму  в каждой части, эту сумму запихнуть в другой вектор( вектор сумм), а затем посчитать сумму всех сумм.
Подскажите как  сделать алгоритм что бы подсчитать кусок и переходить к части что осталось или как поменять мой, так как моя функция выдает не правильный результат, например  на вектор в размере 100 000 он должен выдавать 5000050000, а выдает другое число.

```
long long Sum_MT3(std::vector <int>a)
{
    
    int n = processor_count * 2;
    int count = n;
    int64_t lenght = a.size() / n;
    int64_t sum3;
    while(count!=0)
    {
        if (a.size() % 2 == 0)
        {
            //n = a.size() / 2;


            for ( int64_t i = 0; i <= lenght; i++)
            {
                sum3 = SumOfPart(a, 0, lenght);
                
                d.push_back(sum3);
            }
            
            count--;
            a.resize(a.size() - lenght);
            
    }
        
        sum3 = (SumOfPart(d, 0, d.size()));
        return sum3;
}
```

Comment: Можете более подробно осветить поставленную задачу? Откуда берется это произвольное количество частей, что за вектор размером 100000 вы имели в виду, а если ответ одинаковый для любого вектора данного размера, то почему это так? По вашему объяснению вы делите вектор на части, после чего складываете суммы частей, но в таком случае вы всегда в итоге будете получать просто сумму исходного вектора, не разделенного на части, зачем тогда вы делите его?

Comment: @EzikBro судя по всему это попытка ускорить код с помощью распаралеливания

Comment: Не совсем понятно что у вас вызывает трудности: вектор - это массив, а любой массив характеризуется всего двумя параметрами: точка отсчета (уаазатель га начало массива) и количество элементов. Соответственно, чтобы разделить массив на 4 части нужно просто разделить количество всех элементов на 4 - получится 4 промежутка. Первый начинается с оригинального указателя, второй с оригинальный указатель + количество элементов первого промежутка и т.д.

Comment: Ну или можно итерироваться через n элементов

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Код:

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

const std::size_t chunks_num = 3;

auto main() -> int
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.resize(10001, 3); // sum = 10001 * 3 = 30003

    std::vector<std::future<int>> futures;

    std::size_t offset = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < chunks_num; ++i)
    {
        const auto length =
            (chunks_num - i) > 1    // take rest on the last iteration
            ? v.size() / chunks_num
            : v.size() - offset;

        auto future =
            std::async(std::launch::async,
                   &std::accumulate<decltype(v)::const_iterator, int>,
                   std::cbegin(v) + offset,
                   std::cbegin(v) + offset + length,
                   0);

        offset += length;

        futures.push_back(std::move(future));
    }

    const auto sum =
        std::accumulate(futures.begin(), futures.end(), 0, [](int base, std::future<int>& f)
            { return base + f.get(); });

    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Пояснения: `v` - исходный вектор, он условно разбивается на `chunks_num` частей, каждая из которых передается на вход алгоритму [accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) (из стандартной библиотеки) запускаемому в отдельном потоке.

Я не стал создавать отдельный вектор для сумм, так как объекты `std::future<int>` уже лежат в векторе. Все, что нам нужно сделать - дождаться результата и обновить сумму:

```
return base + f.get();
              ^
              // wait for the result
```

*P.S. Здесь правильнее использовать thread pool, так как в общем случае запуск N потоков для N вычислительных задач - стратегия проигрышная.*

**UPD.:** вариант, предложенный @HolyBlackCat

```
#include <numeric>
#include <execution>

auto main() -> int
{
    std::vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    auto r = std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 0);
    return r;
}
```

[Пример на wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZmVHcQY40Vi6uk8Q).

Comment: Если ставите минусы, не поленитесь объяснить, пожалуйста, за что именно :)

Comment: По поводу того что лучше использовать: сдесь однозначно не стоит использовать async или пул потоков - для таких задач идеально подойдет openmp, с помощью него распаралеливание цикла не потребует (ну или почти не потребует) переписывания кода. А то подобный код сложноват для восприятия

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, возможно, Вы и правы, но никаких упоминаний об OpenMP я в задаче не увидел, а вот C++ там есть. Что касается последнего - субъективно.

Comment: То же самое можно сделать в одну строчку: `std::accumulate(std::execution::par_unseq, v.begin(), v.end(), 0);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, accumulate поддерживает execution policies?

Comment: @isnullxbh Ой, да, пардон. Тогда `std::reduce`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ок, но ни один из установленных на моей машине компилятор не умеет в эти вещи. И, судя по ошибкам, дело в TBB.

Comment: @isnullxbh На каких-то компиляторах нужно дополнительно руками ликовать TBB, чтобы это работало.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо, обновил ответ.